# Socket.io disconnects client socket when transferring large file or message

Tags: file-upload, socket.io

I have written a code to transfer a large file from client to server using `Socket.io` and for doing so, I am breaking the file into small chunks (500KB each block) and sending it to server, but exactly for sending the first chunk of data, client socket will get disconnected and the process gets stopped.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in
[this link](https://github.com/sffc/socketio-file-upload/issues/38)

The problem was with the **chunk (Block) size**. I reduced it to **10KB** for each block I send to server and now it is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

set the maxHttpBufferSize to 1e8 is worked for me

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  maxHttpBufferSize: 1e8, pingTimeout: 60000
});
```

https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#maxhttpbuffersize